# Triggering email out of Spotfire based on conditions

Tags: automation, ironpython, spotfire

Does anyone have experience with triggering an email from Spotfire based on a condition? Say, a sales figure falls below a certain threshold and an email gets sent to the appropriate distribution list. I want to know how involved this would be to do. I know that it can be done using an iron python script, but I'm curious if it can be done based on conditions rather than me hitting "run"?

Answer (score 1):

we actually have a product that does exactly this called the Spotfire Alerting Tool. it functions off of Automation Services and allows you to configure various thresholds for any metrics in the analysis, and then can notify users via email or even SMS.

of course there is the possibility of coding this yourself (the tool is simply an extension developed using the Spotfire SDK) but I can't comment on how to code it.

the best way to get this tool is probably to check with your TIBCO sales rep. if you'd like I can try to reach him on your behalf, but I'll need a bit more info from you. please contact me at nmaresco@tibco.com.

I hope this kind of answer is okay on SO. I don't have a way to reach you privately and this is the best answer I know how to give :)